# proxy setting in adal-node package

Tags: node.js, node-modules, adal

I am trying to generate token to authenticate to Azure AD in my node server using adal-node package().Its working on my local machines but when trying to run on virtual machines its giving below error:

{
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN login.microsoftonline.com login.microsoftonline.com:443
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'login.microsoftonline.com',
host: 'login.microsoftonline.com',
port: 443` }

sample code snippet

```
var authorityUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/53d652a4-6f71-416f-971f-*****'
    var applicationId = '26915ab6-22fc-4017-8741-***************'; // Application Id of app registered under AAD.
    var clientSecret = '2NZtB5mIX1xZaXZ_I6I~-*********'; // Secret generated for app. Read this environment variable.
    var resource = 'https://**************.com'; // URI that identifies the resource for which the token is valid.
    var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);
    context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, applicationId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
            console.log(err);
            res.json(err.stack);
        } else {
           
            console.log(tokenResponse.accessToken);
           
        }
```

Analysis:It looks like proxy issue but unable to figure out how to set proxy url using adal-node package.Kindly suggest the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the proxy server in your application, please refer to the following code

```
const { AuthenticationContext, Logging } = require("adal-node");
const proxy = require("node-global-proxy").default;
proxy.setConfig({
  http: "",
https: ""
});
proxy.start();
const context = new AuthenticationContext(
  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/const { AuthenticationContext, Logging } = require("adal-node");
const proxy = require("node-global-proxy").default;
proxy.setConfig({
  http: "http://149.28.43.184:8080",
});
proxy.start();
const context = new AuthenticationContext(
  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb"
);

Logging.setLoggingOptions({
  log: function (level, message, error) {
    console.log(message);
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
  loggingWithPII: false,
  level: Logging.LOGGING_LEVEL.VERBOSE,
});
var applicationId = ""; // Application Id of app registered under AAD.
var clientSecret = ""; // Secret generated for app. Read this environment variable.
var resource = "";
context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(
  resource,
  applicationId,
  clientSecret,
  function (err, tokenResponse) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("well that didn't work: " + err.stack);
    } else {
      console.log(tokenResponse);
    }
  }
);

proxy.stop()
```